# CSS which takes precedence, inline or the class?

Tags: css

My website has a stylesheet defined in the header as style.css with a selector:

```
.myClass {background:#000;}
```

Now my div looks like:

```
<div class="myClass" style="background:#fff;"> &nbsp; </div>
```

Which one has priority, the inline or the class?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally speaking we can say that all the styles will "cascade" into a new "virtual" style sheet by the following rules, where number three has the highest priority:

1. Browser default
2. Embedded and external stylesheets. Later has precedence over earlier. There IS NOT any inherent difference between embedded and external.
3. Inline style (inside an HTML element)

Source (Edit: of original incorrect information, since corrected both here and there): [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

W3schools explains a lot about CSS and also goes through and shows examples of most things you can do with CSS. Always a good resource if you have questions about something. (Edit: debatable, they were the source of the original wrong answer.)

Comment: W3Schools are not W3C. They're what I'd call impostors.

Comment: I dont think they claim to be related to the w3c I think they just are playing off the w3c's name. The w3c contains a lot of information but doesn't always provide examples for everything. I use both but thats a choice up to you.

Comment: Please See The Below Answer , as this would be the best source for information.

Comment: internal `<style></style>` and `<link>` external stylesheet BOTH HAVE SAME PRIORITY what matters is only order. you can play around with this example https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_multiple

Comment: `w3schools` has already corrected that misleading information. There is no precedence order between external or internal styles, they still have misleading information saying _(in the head section)_. I would not take `w3schools` as a good resource for learning web development.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085898/8851276 on how to override inline style using ```!important```

Answer (score 33):

The order of precedence with CSS is as follows:

1. **!important** (this is a bit hackish though but it is the only way to override an inline style. Try to avoid using this unless really necessary). Example: p {color: blue !important; }
2. **Inline**, such as `<p class="redText" style="color: red;">CSS is awesome</p>`.In this example, the class is ignored if the `redText` class declaration has already tried to define the property of `color:`. Other properties can still be honored though.
3. **Internal** styles - those written inside the `<head><style>` section of an html page.
4. **External** stylesheet which defines styles. Your html document must have a link to this sheet in order to use it. Example, again inside the `<head>` section is: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />`

Check here to brush up on the terminology: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: Is the above answer by me incorrect , someone is deliberately downvoting my answer, i just want to recheck it, can you confirm it ?

Comment: your ans is correct upvoted but raj's covered !important which no one did

Comment: Quote from @godblessstrawberry: internal `<style></style>` and external `<link>` stylesheet BOTH HAVE SAME PRIORITY what matters is only order.

Answer (score 9):

The order of precedence with CSS is as follows:

1. **Inline**, such as `<div id="orange" class="green" style="color: red;">This is red</div>`.In this example, the `class` is ignored if the `green` class declaration has already tried to define the property of color.Also `id` is also ignored if it has tried to define the color.
2. **Id Selector**  , such as   `#orange { color: orange; }`
3. **Class Selectors** , such as  `.green { color: green; }`
4. **Element Selectors**  ,such as `div { color: black; }`

Mozilla Developer Network Documentation Has Well Written Documentation on That Which [Says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Howto/CSS_FAQ)

> When multiple rules apply to a certain element, the rule chosen depends on its style [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance#Specificity). **Inline style** (in HTML style attributes) has the highest specificity and will override any selectors, followed by **ID selectors**, then **class selectors**, and eventually **element selectors**.

The text color of the below  will therefore be red.

```css
  div { color: black; }
   #orange { color: orange; }
   .green { color: green; }
```

```html
 
<div id="orange" class="green" style="color: red;">This is red</div>
```

---

<sup>Please Consult [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) for any HTML, CSS  or JavaScript Knowledge, w3school does not have a very good reputation in developers community. For Further Info On This Matter Please Visit [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There is no 3.Internal or 4.External precedence. Whichever stylesheet comes last in the html page which will get the precedence.
Eg.

```
<style></style>
<link> </link> <!-- Precedence -->


<link> </link> 
<style></style> <!-- Precedence -->
```