# Link text color on hover

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have a problem and basically I want to do this

```css
.buttonar {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: #008CBA;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button2:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<a class="buttonar button2" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="alternate">button</a>
```

But the problem is, my website already has a `template.css` (Joomla website) in which styling for a, a:link, a:hover etc are already set. I want my button to appear exactly as on the code snippet output but I cannot seem to get it working as the link stays blue ((barely visible) set by template) or it only changes color when I hover over the link itself and not the button (created another class for a:link and a:hover).

Can anyone assist me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'C' in CSS stands for Cascading. This means that CSS will look at items at the top, then as it goes down the sheets, it will overwrite them.

This applies to how you put the files in your HTMl as well:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <!-- Insert Joomla CSS here -->
    <!-- Insert your custom CSS here -->
</head>
```

This will apply the Joomla CSS first, but then your custom styles overwrite it.

On second read...

...if you're talking about just styling, the `.button2` selects the element that has `class="button2"` in your HTML. Simply add that class in the HTML to the button you want styled and it will work.

Comment: I have the same code on my site but the text/link in the button doesn't get styled, it looks like all other links on the website instead of white and on hover black.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline your style in the button, and it will take precedence.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749569/css-which-takes-precedence-inlne-or-the-class).

Answer (score 0):

The fix may be as simple as adding an !important to your css. This hijacks the cascading rules and should override your template.css rules.

Also, make sure that wherever you place your own css rules, place it AFTER template.css is called on your page. It may not be enough to place it anywhere in the head tags. I would first find out where template.css is being called (usually in a link tag) and place your own css with an !important marker after it.

For info on this: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Sung