# Why does an IF condition with no statements inside removes the border of an element?

Tags: javascript

I can't tell if this is a bug or not.

```js
function moncheck() { 

    if($(".mon").attr("style", "border")) { 
      
    }

    $(this).attr("style", "border: 1px solid red")

}


$(".mon").on("click", moncheck)
```

```css
.mon { 
    width:100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover { 
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div id="monlist">
           
            <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">
           
        </div>
```

As you can see, the `if` condition has no statements, and you click on an image, it gets a red border, then when you click on another image, what is expected to happen is for that second image to also get a red border, and now both images should have a red border, since at no point was the border of the first image removed. Yet, it does get removed because of the `if` condition. If you go ahead and comment out the `if` condition, you will see that the border remains on all images as you click. Why?

Example:

```js
function moncheck() { 
    imgurl = this.src;

    //if($(".mon").attr("style", "border")) { 
      
    //}

    $(this).attr("style", "border: 1px solid red")

}


$(".mon").on("click", moncheck)
```

```css
.mon { 
    width:100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover { 
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  
  
  <div id="monlist">
           
            <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">
           
        </div>
```

This does not happen if I use `css`, instead of `attr`.

```
 if($(".mon").css("border")) { 
      
    }
```

This will result in each `img` retaining the border. Why?

And another behavior I can't explain is the removal of the hover effect when I remove the border on click.

```js
function moncheck() { 

    if($(".mon").css("border")) { 
        $(".mon").css("border", "none")
    }

    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red")
}


$(".mon").on("click", moncheck)
```

```css
.mon { 
    width:100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover { 
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div id="monlist">
           
            <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
            <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">
           
        </div>
```

As you can see, when I use `css` to remove the border, the hover effect is removed as well. Why? The hover should not be removed.

Comment: _"the if condition has no statement"_. It does: `$(".mon").attr("style", "border")` this sets the `style` attribute to `"border"`, effectively getting rid of anything that was in that attribute before

Comment: @blex By why is the border being removed? When you click again, shouldn't the if condition then add the attribute of style with the property of border to all `'mon` elements? Why is the border on the previous one removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an `if` statement, the condition you provide has to be evaluated to return something like `true` or `false`. If it returns someting else, it will be evaluated as `truty` or `falsy` anyway... because it has to decide whether or not to execute the code block provided within the curly braquets.

```js
console.log($(".mon").attr("style", "border"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mon">"Mon" element</div>
```

So in that first case, `$(".mon").attr("style", "border")` is a "setter" for the style attribute. So while being evaluated, the style attribute is setted. If you inpect that snippet code, you will see:

```
<div class="mon" style="border">"mon" element</div>
```

The setter returns the jQuery object which is truty... Like any object (even an empty object) is.

A falsy value is an emty string, a NaN, a null an undefined value...

---

About your second case:

```js
console.log($(".mon").css("border"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mon"></div>
```

`$(".mon").css("border")` returns `0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)` which is truty because it is a non-empty string.

So then all the `.mon` element will be added a `style="border:none;` which orverides the :hover border because an inline style attribute has precedence over the stylesheet.

---

Now if you want to add a red border on the clicked image while keeping the hover border effect, I suggest you to use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` like this:

```js
function moncheck() { 
  $(".mon").removeClass("redBorder")
  $(this).addClass("redBorder")
}


$(".mon").on("click", moncheck)
```

```css
.mon {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.redBorder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="monlist">

  <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">

</div>
```

Comment: I get that because `attr()` is a method, it gets executed inside the `if` condition, which sets an empty `border` to all `.mon` elements, but ... why is the border getting removed? Shouldn't it set the border to ALL elements instead of removing it?

Comment: Is it because the border is empty, so i.e. it does SET the border to all elements, but because the border is empty, it's like nothing has been set?

Comment: Setting an inline `border` property with no value is interpreted as `border: none;` And again, an inline style attribute has precedence over the style sheet, which is why the hover effect does not apply. -- Use a class for the red border... It is easier to play with the elements and is a better practice.

Comment: But why does removing the border prevents the hover from adding a new one? If you go and add `border: none` to the `.mon { }` on CSS, it's not going to stop the hover from adding it again.

Comment: Again... Precedence is the key for that specific point. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6749618/2159528).

Comment: Right, I get it now. I actually do wanted to achieve that very same effect. I didn't want the border to remain. I just couldn't understand why is it being removed. Do you think this is a good way of doing it? Isn't it a bit.. unsophisticated? Do you think there's a better approach to achieving this very same effect?

Comment: I am not sure about "sophisticated" or not. If it works like you wish, it's fine.

Comment: I'm sorry I got confused again. If adding $(".mon").attr("style", "border") sets an inline attribute of border: none, which should remove the hover.. then, why is the hover still there? and why if I add $(".mon").attr("style", "border: none") instead, the hover is now gone?

Comment: is it not because, empty border is not the same as border:none? That is the only explanation.

Comment: You are right... I was wrong saying it is interpreted as `border: none`. It "clears" the border property of the inline style attribute. Read [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2442-clearing-inline-css-properties-with-jquery.htm)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but I am just really caught into this, and is frustrating me. Just out of pure curiosity, I am trying to make an `if` condition based on whether or not the element has a `css` `border`, not an attribute, but I can't make it work. `if($(".mon").css("border") != "")` this returns `true`, and I don't understand why. `if($(".mon").css("border") != null)` this also returns true. Even `if($(".mon").css("border") != "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)")` returns true. It's frustrating me. Why does it keep returning true!? I even removed the `hover` just in case, and still its `true`

Comment: `$(".mon")` returns a collection of elements. When you apply the `.css()` getter method on it, it will get a value for the first element in the collection. Try using `$(this)`. -- Also, you could try to be a little more specific and get the `border-width`. The condition would look like: `if( parseInt($(this).css("border-width")) > 0 ) {...}`. ;)

Comment: But this is not going to work, because the idea is when you click on a second img, the border of the first one to be removed, so that's why my idea was to check if any `mon` has a border, and if it does, to then apply the empty border to all, since there's no way of knowing which specific element has it. Pretty much my idea was instead of just `$(".mon").attr("style", "border")` followed by `$(this).css("border", "1px solid red")`, to put the first inside a condition, but as I said, it couldn't find a way to check if a border has been set via css.

Comment: Also now that I think about it, when using `css()`, even if it gets the value of the first element only, it should still not be `true`, because non of the elements have a border when I first click on them, yet it keeps returning `true`.

Comment: Agree. I don't know how you test it. Do you console log it? like `console.log( $(this).css("border") != "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)" )` ?

Comment: Console log just returns `true`. Don't worry about it anymore. I've settled with the one I have, and moved on :) Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`$(".mon").attr("style", "border")` sets the border to nothing - you are not testing if it is set.

Explanation:

You click and

```
$(".mon").attr("style", "border")
```

removes border from ALL elements with class .mon - then

```
$(this).attr("style", "border: 1px solid red")
```

sets the red border on ONLY the clicked element `$(this)`

---

I suggest you toggle a class instead

Also don't add extra jQuery

NOTE: The computed style is overwritten by the hover. If you remove the hover from the CSS you will see how it changes on click

```js
console.log($(".mon").css("border"))

if($(".mon").css("border").includes("0px")) console.log("No border")

const moncheck = function() {

  let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this);
  console.log(compStyles.getPropertyValue("border"))
  $(this).toggleClass("withBorder");
  compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this);
  console.log(compStyles.getPropertyValue("border"))
  

}


$(".mon").on("click", moncheck);
```

```css
.mon {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.withBorder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="monlist">

  <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">

</div>
```

If you WANT to test the style, you can do this, but only if you SET the style or it is set inline

```js
const moncheck = function() {
  if (!$(this).attr("style")) { 
    $(this).attr("style","border : 1px solid red");
  }  
  else $(this).attr("style","border");
}

$(".mon").on("click", moncheck)
```

```css
.mon {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.mon:hover {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="monlist">

  <img src="https://cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/ufn/image/upload/u7cdzxvxu69pmubmtltc.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/F-898.jpg" class="mon">
  <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/close-up-of-tulips-blooming-in-field-royalty-free-image-1584131616.jpg?crop=0.630xw:1.00xh;0.186xw,0&resize=640:*" class="mon">

</div>
```

Comment: So it sets the border.. so why is the border from the previous img getting removed then?

Comment: And why is it not testing if it is set? It's inside the condition.

Comment: See explanation now

Comment: See updated code to test the style exists

Comment: Why does it remove the border is my question? `attr("style", "border"` ADDS a border, so why is it being removed?

Comment: Attr style border adds an EMPTY border statement so without colour or width

Comment: Is there a way to test if a css style is added or not? I want to test if css "border" has been added, not the attribute.

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('style').includes('border'))`

Comment: This is `attr`, not `css`.

Comment: See update. The computed style is overwritten by the hover. If you remove the hover from the CSS you will see how it changes on click

Comment: I already tested it without the hover, and it again returns `true`. `if($(".mon").css("border") != "")` this returns `true`, and I don't understand why. `if($(".mon").css("border") != null)` this also returns `true`. Even `if($(".mon").css("border") != "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)")` returns `true`.

Comment: The first time I click on any of the `img`, no border is applied anywhere, so the condition should not be `true`, yet it's always `true`.

Comment: You hover sets the border

Comment: I told you, I removed the hover from the CSS.

Comment: `if($(".mon").css("border") != null) {  alert("NOW") }` this is triggered on every `img` i click. I have removed the hover from CSS. Any ideas why? Why is the `if` returning `true`? Non of the images have a border. So why? Is this a proper way of checking if the property `border` is set?

Comment: So `$(".mon").css("border")` is never null. It is `0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)` when not set. So the test is `if($(".mon").css("border").includes("0px")) console.log("No border")`

Comment: Well, then why is `if($(".mon").css("border") != "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)")` also returning `true`?

Comment: What is `include("0px")`? Why is that needed? Why isn't just `if($(".mon").css("border") != "0px none rgb(0, 0, 0)")` working?

Comment: I just tested this `if($(".mon").css("border").includes("0px"))` and it again returns `true`.

Comment: Not includes - come on. And you can test the whole string