# How do i re-enable link hover effect

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a quiz game,(note that the Answer options are made of anchor tags)

I added code in the options.forEach eventListener, that would set the options pointer-events to "none" so that you cant choose another answer once one has been clicked.

// Option BTN Events

```
// Only select one option
if ("clicked") {
  options.forEach((op) => {
    op.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  });
}
```

});
});
I tried: to make the btn.eventListener ( which is the next button ) among other things, set the bg-color back to gray, and set the options style.pointerEvents = "auto"; so that you can click an option for the next question.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentQuestion += 1;
  getQuestion();
  options.forEach((op) => {
    op.style.backgroundColor = $btnCol;
    op.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  });
});
```

Problem: This code works for re-enabling the ability to click an option again, but I want the hover effect to come back as well. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're setting the background color in javascript and it is applied to the element in inline level (style="background-color: red;") which is come before in terms of precedence from extarnel css file.

For better explantion: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749569/css-which-takes-precedence-inline-or-the-class)

And the solution for that you should add `!important` statement in your external css file.

Here is an example:

```css
.a {
  background-color: red;
}
.a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  background-color: red;
}
.b:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="a" style="background-color: red;">without !important</div>
<div class="b" style="background-color: red;">with !important</div>
```

As you can see here the one without the `!important` isn't changing color when hover but the one with it is actually changing.

So you should add `!important` to your code in the hover section.