# how can i change the color of my svg when hovered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im makign this landing page and, my figma says that that, when the button icon is hovered i need to change the background color to white and the svg file to gray. Change the background color was ease busy but changinf the svg color was hard and i still didnt manage to do so can you help me?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

i {
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.topNav {
    gap: 20px
}

i:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    fill: #000;
}

svg:hover {
    fill: black
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <nav class="d-flex flex-column bg-secondary vh-100 justify-content-between custom-width" style="width: fit-content;">
        <div class="topNav d-flex flex-column ">
            <img src="./src/logo.svg" alt="">
            <i class="bi bi-app" style="color: white"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-globe2" style="color: white"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-bar-chart" style="color: white"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="bottomNav d-flex flex-column">
            <i class="bi bi-gear" style="color: white"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-bell-fill" style="color: white"></i>
            <i class="bi bi-person-circle" style="color: white"></i>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <span>This is the test page</span>

    <script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I tried using 'fill' on hover css and i also tried to use 'color' but none of them worked so im kinda clueless.

Comment: I think you want to change the styling of svg that you have loaded using <img /> element?? Right??

Comment: You can not manipulate stuff inside an SVG via your page's stylesheet, if you embed the SVG via an `img` element. That is only possible, if you put the SVG _code_ into your HTML directly. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap icons are based on a font. Each icon is a text character. Therefore you'd change the color of the icons with the CSS property `color`.

In your HTML you are specifying the color with inline CSS: `<i class="bi bi-app" style="color: white"></i>`. You are trying to override this color on `:hover` in your CSS. However, [inline CSS always takes precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085898/1427563). That is, when the browser sees inline CSS, it will prefer to render those styles over anything defined in an external CSS stylesheet.

You need to remove the inline style and put it in your stylesheet, where it will be treated appropriately. For example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}
i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
i:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
  <i class="bi bi-app"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-globe2"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i>
</body>
```

Comment: I think it would look even better if you changed it to a cursor on hover.